# React Native setInterval running 5 or 6 times after clearInterval has been ran

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, setinterval

I am currently developing an app in React Native that includes a stopwatch that is stopped when the phones Gyroscope picks up a certain amount of movement. To do this I am using a setInterval to check for updates on the Gyroscope and if requirements are met, stop the timer. However, the issue arises when the setInterval is running usually 5-6 times after being stopped by both clearInterval and using a hook to check if the game has started. Currently the setInterval is set to 1 ms but it still has the same issue no matter the interval whether it be 1000ms or 10000ms.

```
const stopwatchINT = setInterval(() => {
 if (gameStarted) {
  if (data.x > 0.2) {
    clearInterval(stopwatchINT)
    let endTimer = performance.now()
    setTimeTook(Math.round(endTimer - startTimer) + 'ms')
    playSound()
    setContainer(WHITE)
    setGameStarted(false)
    setReactionScreenDisplay({'select': 'none','singleCreate': 'none', 'reactionGame': 'none', 'flash': 'none', 'timeTook': 'block'})
  }
 }
}, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I have solved the issue. For anyone who gets stuck on this you can enclose the setInterval in a useEffect which was what was throwing me as I forgot to pass the hooks in the array. For example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (isStart) {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (count > 0) {
                setCount(count - 1)
            } else {
                setCount('Times up');
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}, [isStart]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).